# Каким образом можно вывести последние 5 записей от текущей WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

думаю каждый видел такой функционал что есть статья а в низу последние статьи. Тут немного сложнее ибо надо выводить не последние 5 из всех а от текущей статьи. Имея ID текущей статьи каким образом можно получить последние 5 до неё

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'post',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'date_query'    => array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'before'   => get_the_date()
    ),
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```